# Socket.io in c#... SocketIoClientDotNet and SocketIO4net Failed

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I want to develop a simple C# program to connect to socket.io v1.x on Node.js

I have tried [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/) but it failed!

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
socket.Emit("hi");
});

socket.On("hi", (data) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    socket.Disconnect();
});
```

When I run the program, the server tell me that there is two connections, but the property:

```
socket.Connected = false;
```

always!!!

This is the 4th day of searching on the web for a solution but I couldn't find anything!

Who have a way to connect to Socket.io using C#??!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

be sure nodejs server work and

c# .net 4.0up code

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var options = new IO.Options() { IgnoreServerCertificateValidation = true, AutoConnect = true, ForceNew = true };
options.Transports = new List<string>() { "websocket" };
_instance = IO.Socket("ws://localhost:3000", options);
_instance.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
    _connected = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
});
_instance.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
{
    _connected = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
});
```