# How to connect socket IO server using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, socket.io

I've developed a socket server using node express & very easily able to connect it with js `socket.io.js` library, but I'm unable to connect with C#. Any help will be appreciated.

Node code as server:

```
socketIO.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on("connected", function (userId) {
        // console.log(socket.id);
        console.log(userId);
        users[userId] = socket.id;
    });
    }
```

JS client-side code:

```
var applicationId = 1;

var socketIO = io("ws://192.168.10.210:8989");
socketIO.emit("connected", applicationId);


socketIO.on("messageReceived", function (data) {
   console.log(data);
```

});

C# code which is not working:

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int applicationId = 1;

        string serverUrl = "ws://192.168.10.210:8989";

        var socket = IO.Socket(serverUrl);

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");
            socket.Emit("connected", applicationId);
        });

        socket.On("messageReceived", data =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();

        socket.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working in your c# code, do you get any errors?

Comment: @MarkBaijens no error. Just blank console. Server also not showning connected but for JS code it showing connected.

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190867/socket-io-in-c-socketioclientdotnet-and-socketio4net-failed

Comment: from SocketIoClientDotNet github's page ... *THIS PROJECT IS DEPRECATED* ... last commit - 4 years ago ...

Comment: @Selvin can you suggest the latest one pls?